# Renderin TabularInline data with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Is it possible to render tabular data to edit with crispy forms,
Django admin has this feature with TabularInline.

Lets say my formset layout declared as below.

```
formset_layout =  Layout(
    Div(
        'like_website',
        'favorite_number',
        css_id = 'special-fields'
    ),
)
```

And my main forms layout may be

```
main_form_layout = Layout(
MultiField(
    'Tell us your favorite stuff {{ username }}',
    Div(
        formset_layout
    ),
    'favorite_color',
    'favorite_food',
    'notes'
)
)
```

I want to use formset layout inside an another layout, So that I can put it inside an accordion or something.

Comment: I created 2 form helper, one of them for the inline entry, got it working but , I m looking for a way to put this inline forms layout inside an another form layout something like.

Comment: Sounds like you've almost answered your own question then.

Comment: extended my question to be more specific, got hit enter last time I was commenthing, thanks